# How to download multiple images from a web server?

Tags: windows, images, download, webserver

I would like to download *.jpg images from a web server. The web page (and web server) is secured so that I have to give my credentials to access it. There is no one web page which has links to the images, but I can use direct URL:s to access those images. The *.jpg images are named using numbers, e.g.

```
http://www.[somewebpage].com/1.jpg
http://www.[somewebpage].com/2.jpg
http://www.[somewebpage].com/3.jpg
...and so on
```

There are hundreds of images, how can I download them at once? I was thinking of using wget or similar, but how can I give my credentials in wget (for the secured web page)? Or can I use some kind of download manager (downthemall in Firefox or some alternative)?

Comment: Does it have to be in chrome? because there's a way to do it in Firefox that's really simple.

Comment: No, I edited the question.

Comment: Wget supports --user and --password arguments. You can also look into --load-cookies.

Answer (score 1):

Click on the wrench and select "Save Page As".  In the "Save As Type" drop down at the bottom of the save dialog, make sure "Web Page, Complete" is selected.  The images, as well as the javascript and CSS in the page will be saved to the a folder names with a similar name to the file name you enter for the web page.  If you want to get rid of the Javascript and CSS, open the resulting folder in explorer, and sort it by file type. This should allow you to quickly delete the files which are not images.  This will work in both FireFox and Google Chrome.

In FireFox, right click on the page, and select "View Page Info". Then go to the media tab.  go to the list of images, and press CTRL+A to select them all. Then when you go to "Save As" it allows you to select a folder, and will download all the images on the page to the folder.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I edited the question, I don't have links to those images on a single web page.

Comment: There is no single web page containing the images (or URL's to the images). So I think that the method you are suggesting does not work in this case.